# How to implement "abstract" property initializers in Swift

Tags: swift

So far I have only worked on Objectiv-C projects and now started my first Swift project.

I know that Swift does not support abstract classes but I would like to know what is the best way to model / solve this in Swift:

```
// Abstract implementation
public abstract class MyClass {
    private SomeBaseClass someProperty; 

    MyClass() {
        initProperties();
    }

    abstract void initProperties();  // Init someProperty with some child class of SomeBaseClass.
}

// Objectiv-C
@implementation MyClass

- (id)init {
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
        [self initProperties];     
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)initProperties {
    // Override in inherited classes
}


// Swift
class MyClass {
    // Should not be optional since MyClass should be required to have someProperty != nil
    let someProperty: SomeBaseClass;

    override init() {
        super.init();
        initProperties();
    }

    func initProperties() {
         // Cannot be empty since someProperty is non-optional and needs to be initialized
         // Cannot be empty since Swift does not support abstract methods
    }
}
```

Of course it would be possible to define `someProperty` as optional `SomeBaseClass?` but in this case every time the property is used it has to be tested and unwrapped.

Is there a better way to solve this?

**EDIT:**

I know that Swift uses protocols to create an abstraction similar to abstract classes. However I do not understand how this concept can solve the concrete problem / question.

In other programming languages the abstract class `MyClass` can use the property `someProperty` in many different places while leaving the burden to initialize the property with a value with its concrete subclasses.

Although I read the article linked by @MohamendS and the answers to the possible dublicate answer I do not understand how to achieve the same using protocols.

- `MyClass` has only one *abstract* function while all other functions are implemented. Thus MyClass itself cannot be a protocol since protocols cannot implement functions (can they?)
- `MyClass` could only implement another protocol which defines that there has to be a `initProperties` method. But in this case `MyClass` would need to provide an implementation of this method which brings us back to the same problem.

I guess I can't see the wood for the trees, but how can protocols help here?

Comment: "I do not understand how this concept can solve the concrete problem / question." This is the heart of the issue: this question is not concrete. It's an abstract problem. The answer for the above code, if it really were the actual code you were planning to ship, is "delete `someProperty`, it's never used." But for your *concrete* problem that almost certainly is not the right answer. We just don't know what your concrete problem is, so it's hard to discuss what protocol would be appropriate. Protocols are a different way of thinking about problems than abstract classes.

Comment: updated perhaps this could give you the idea

Answer (score 4):

Abstraction concept in `Swift` is used with `protocols`, i suggest reading [this](https://medium.com/@abhimuralidharan/all-about-protocols-in-swift-11a72d6ea354) article to know more and here is an example

```
 protocol Abstraction {
    var foo: String { get }
    func fee()
    init(with foo: String)
}

class A: Abstraction {

    required init(with foo: String) {
        self.foo = foo 
    }
    var foo: String = ""

    func fee() {

      }
}
```

Edit: on your point, that

> protocols can't implement functions

You can't but what you can do is extends those protocols using extension and give them an initial implementation therefore you don't have to implement them in the class and you can when you feel you'd like to, check the code below

```
    class A: Abstraction {

    required init(with foo: String) {
        self.foo = foo
    }
    var foo: String = ""

    //you don't have to implement func foo anymore as its extended in the extension
}

extension Abstraction {
    func fee() {
        print("ok")
    }
}

let a = A(with: "foo")
a.fee() // this will trigger the extension implementation,
```

Now to use `init` inside the `extension` body so you wont have to type them in each confirmation, check out the code below

```
protocol Abstraction {
    var foo: String { get set }
    func fee()
    init()
    init(with foo: String)
}


class A: Abstraction {
    required init() { }
    var foo: String = ""

    //you don't have to implement func foo anymore as its extended in the extension 
   // you don't have to implement the custom init anymore too 

}

extension Abstraction {
    init(with foo: String) {
        self.init()
        self.foo = foo
    }
    func fee() {
        print("ok")
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes and it is worth pointing out that you can have an `init` method in a protocol

Comment: @JoakimDanielson i added it in the example

Answer (score 3):

There are many possible answers to this question depending on how MyClass is used. As written, there's of course no reason for `someProperty` to be in the base class at all, and there's definitely no reason for an `initProperties()` method (that should be in `init`).

I realize this is "just an example," but it demonstrates a common problem of creating hierarchies that aren't needed. There are ways to write this code using a semi-abstract base class, but generally that should be avoided, so the first question is what you're using this for and can we avoid this problem entirely?

To answer the question as given, you'd probably start by making a default `SomeBaseClass`, so that the abstract class can just assign `someProperty = SomeBaseClass()`.

If that's impossible, generally you'd use a `!` type:

```
let someProperty: SomeBaseClass!
```

And you implement `initProperties()` with a `fatalError`:

```
func initProperties() { fatalError("Implement in subclass") }
```

Alternately, it can be convenient to implement `someProperty` as a computed variable, and implement it based on some other property in the subclasses

```
var someProperty: SomeBaseClass { fatalError() }
```

But this is really a last resort. Any time you find yourself having to write `fatalError` you're probably on the wrong track, and you don't need a trick to get around it; you need to reconsider the problem.

You should first think about how `MyClass` is *used*, and consider whether it can be a value type. Separately, you should think about whether it can be a protocol that matches the use case. Protocols are not just abstract interfaces that hide implementations. They are a view onto a conforming type to solve a specific problem. That's why there's a Collection protocol that provides access to dozens of algorithms for numerous, otherwise unrelated types, not an `ArrayProtocol` just to hide the implementation of Array. Don't turn `MyClass` into `MyClassProtocol`. Ask what kinds of algorithms want to use types like this one.

When you find yourself creating interlocking hierarchies of types (subclasses of something that require subclasses of some other thing), you have often sliced the problem in the wrong direction. You should rethink whether you could slice the problem so that the varying parts of `SomeBaseClass` are actually part of `MyClass` (often this makes `SomeBaseClass` simpler; for example being pure data rather than having logic).

There's no one right answer here. It depends on the nature of `MyClass`, so we can't really discuss it in abstract terms. Like abstract classes, solving abstract problems often leads you down the wrong roads. It's often better to start with concrete types and then find their similarities and extract them.

Even with that said, it's worth showing what a simple, naive protocol would look like here. (It's possible this is even the correct protocol.)

```
public protocol MyProtocol {
    var someProperty: SomeBaseClass { get }
}
```

That's it. That's all you actually express in your current abstract class (and it's not actually clear whether `someProperty` is public; if it's private, this protocol would be empty).

An implementing struct would then look like:

```
struct MyStruct: MyProtocol {
    var someProperty: SomeBaseClass
}
```

Or if you wanted a reference type, you could use a final class:

```
final class MyClass: MyProtocol {
    var someProperty: SomeBaseClass
    init() {
        someProperty = ...
    }
}
```

Or if you wanted inheritance, you could use a non-final class:

```
class MyClass: MyProtocol {
    var someProperty: SomeBaseClass
    init() {
        someProperty = ...
    }
}
```